# Inject Maven parameter into Java class

Tags: java, maven, code-injection

I would like to inject settings.xml profile parameters into Java class. I tried to use maven-annotation-plugin but values came as null. I wonder if this is because this plugin is designed for Mojo

Setting.xml snippet

```xml
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>APP_NAME</id>
      <properties>
        <test.email>USER_EMAIL</test.email>
        <test.password>USER_PASSWORD</test.password>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

In class

```
@Parameter(defaultValue = "test.email", readonly = true)
private String userEmail;

@Parameter(defaultValue = "test.password", readonly = true)
private String userPassword;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use `maven-resources-plugin` to generate a `.properties` file and avoid generating code.

```
<build>
  <resources>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
<build>
```

And create the file `src/main/resources/com/example/your/file.properties`:

```
testMail = ${test.email}
propertyName = ${maven.variable.name}
```

In Java access it with:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/example/your/file.properties")
```

To go further, you can enforce the presence of the `test.email` property with `maven-enforcer-plugin`:

```
<build>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>enforce-email-properties</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>enforce</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <rules>
            <requireProperty>
              <property>test.email</property>
              <message>
                The 'test.email' property is missing.
                It must [your free error text here]
              </message>
            </requireProperty>
          </rules>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</build>
```

Comment: I was considering that too, but there is always human factor that some developer/contributor commits his private credential to repo. I though settings.xml would be safer solution

Comment: I completed the answer, as you can see, the credentials can be set in `settings.xml` or on command line.

Comment: @shellholic  is it possible to fetch values of properties into java class. I know for fact we can read property file and get all the values in java. But I want something like variable injections. or please let me know if there is any new library that help me automatic variable injection into java class during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Maven to generate a [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) file and [load](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)  it in your Java Class.